# Is "dress" in this sense a stative verb?

Tags: stative-verbs

When one uses "dress" to show the particular way that one dresses, is dress a stative verb?

For example, "She **dresses** well" or "He **dresses** extravagantly."

Comment: I don't really understand how your examples are relevant, but I suppose you'd have to say this particular usage is indeed "stative", since we *wouldn't* normally say *"She is dressing well"* to describe what is in effect [a "state", rather than an "action"](http://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/what-are-state-verbs)

Comment: These are [generic verb uses](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/generictoafault.pdf), which can only occur with semantically active verbs. _She's dressing better these days_ is a perfectly normal thing to say (assuming one normally comments judgementally on others' clothing), and so is an imperative: _Dress better than that to succeed!_

Comment: Just curious: What purpose could an answer to this question serve?  AFAIK this distinction is irrelevant in English.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  It appears to me that in the phrases used as examples a result is being described, not an activity.